# Adding a search feature to HTML5 select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

I need to add a search bar that will allow me to filter the unwanted options from the list. I need to use select and I need to do this without a plugin, what's the easiest way to do this? I tried using the select2 plugin, but it screwed up my entire application, because it depended on some logic written by a previous developer. The data population is already taken care of, so I don't need to do anything to populate it.

I also need to point out that I need to be able to type inside the textbox, something which html5 select doesn't allow me to do and be able to have a dropdown arrow that allows me to see the full list. Can we do it with html5 alone through some trick, or I need a lot of javascript to do this?

Comment: That's a nice todo list but.... where is the source code of your attempt(s)? This isn't a free programming service where you drop a request and others do the work for you... Can you please update your question with your attempt(s) and I'm sure someone will debug it and explain why it isn't functioning as intended and maybe offer a solution. Please avoid throwing source code into the question with "It doesn't work" Detail is the key to getting a good solution.

Comment: It wasn't working because the jQuery selector depended on select and select2 somehow got rid of the html I had in my list. There was another issue, because the jQuery validate plugin somehow screwed up when I tried to validate my input, but I couldn't really debug it properly and since the select2 plugin sometimes caused some display issue when calling creating the dropdown through ajax even after I used a promise and made sure the dropdown got created after the event was triggered, I thought I might ask how I could do this without any plugin. The code is probably 500-600 lines long.

Comment: I mean there are two things I would like to do: make it so that the select textbox is separated into a textfield in which the user can enter text and a dropdown menu, because the default behavior just merges the textbox with the dropdown, and I would like to find the simplest way to remove options from a list depending on what the user enters in real time. You don't need to see the code. (Why did you delete your comment?)

Comment: The reason for asking for the source code is to ensure your existing function are not conflicting or causing a syntax error which will cause the rest to fail but I understand if the source code is too big it can be a pain to try cut it down. Use your browsers console for checking errors and maybe **guest271314** answer will be along the right lines of what you're looking for?

Comment: Well, the problems were caused by a mismatch in the selector and the html layout and some plugin incompatibilities. I don't know the exact reasons, but I posted this question in order to find the simplest way to solving the issue I had.

Comment: @jarvan _"Well, the problems were caused by a mismatch in the selector and the html layout and some plugin incompatibilities"_ No `javascript` appears at Question? How can issue relating to `javascript` be resolved using description at Question?

Comment: Have you tried using the jQuery chosen plugin? [https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Answer (score 14):

Use [`<datalist>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) element

```html
<label for="cars">Search cars: <input list="cars" name="cars" type="text">
</label>
<datalist id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Is there a way to maintain the select tag and somehow add a drop arrow in there without too much javascript or none at all? I knew about datalist, but I needed to keep the select attribute to make it work proper.

Comment: @jarvan What is purpose of using `<select>` element? Yes, it is possible. You could also use `<ul>`, `<li>` elements, retrieve `.textContent` or `dataset` of element for a value

Comment: I need to keep it to make the application work, because there's a jQuery selector that uses select to retrieve data.

Comment: _"because there's a jQuery selector that uses select to retrieve data"_ Can you include `javascript` at Question?

Comment: Sorry, I added the javascript tag, because I couldn't really word the question right with the word javascript in there.

Answer (score 3):

Batter You use `<datalist>` in stand of the `<select>`

```
<input placeholder="Type Car Name" list="cars">
 <datalist id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
 </datalist>
```

**Note** : The datalist tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.

Answer (score -3):

This answer is about 1.5 yrs after the Q, but maybe it helps someone.

I know you said "without a plugin", but you might take a look at the jQuery Chosen plugin.  I wasn't crazy about Select2 for similar reasons.  I am now using Chosen for a searchable Select.  It was fairly easy to add to my existing application that was using the standard select.  It seems Chosen uses your existing Select, hides it, but properly marks selected items so the form processing continues to work.  Might need some styling to fit into your application styling.

HTH someone.