# Search on Select option

Tags: javascript, php, html

i trying to make sreach function on my select in html ,when selected will display value to other input box ,but when i trying to do search function on select its work but will not display value to input box .

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 


<select name="select" id="selUser" class="sku">    
  <option value="">Select Option</option>
    <?php
      $conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','skua'); 
        $query = "SELECT * FROM diy Where SKU LIKE '%DIY-PROC%'     ";
         $result = $conn->query($query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo '<option value="'.htmlspecialchars ($row['Description']).'|'.($row['Sell_Price']).'|'.($row['Cost_Price']).'|'.($row['Qty']).'|'.($row['SKU']).' ">'.($row['SKU']).'</option>';
                            }?>
                </select>
              
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="CPUdes" class="desc"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="CPUsell" ID="S1" class="sell_price"></td>
            <td><input type="text"  name="CPUcost"  ID="C1"class="cost_price"></td>
            <td> <input type="text"  name="CPUqty" class="qty"></td>
            <td> <input type="text"  name="CPUsku" class="CPUsku" hidden></td>
            <td hidden> <input type="text" hidden name="TYPE"  value="CPU"></td>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
                  const spt = document.querySelector('.sku');
                    const result = document.querySelector('.desc');
                    const result1 = document.querySelector('.sell_price');
                    const result2 = document.querySelector('.cost_price');
                    const result3 = document.querySelector('.qty');
                    const result4 = document.querySelector('.CPUsku');
                    spt.addEventListener('change',function(e){

                    let val = spt.value;
                    const aspt = val.split("|");
                    const select = aspt[0];
                    const select1= aspt[1];
                    const select2= aspt[2];
                    const select3= aspt[3];
                    const select4= aspt[4];
                    result.value= select;
                    result1.value= select1;
                    result2.value= select2;
                    result3.value= select3;
                    result4.value= select4;
                    });
</script>
```

**JQuery i tested**

```
       $(document).ready(function(){
 
  // Initialize select2
  $("#selUser").select2();

  // Read selected option
  $('#but_read').click(function(){
    var username = $('#selUser option:selected').text();
    var userid = $('#selUser').val();

    $('#result').html("id : " + userid + ", name : " + username);

  });
});
```

**Script sources**
[https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js)
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js
**Suppose be**
[Before select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKwkB.png)
[After select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXUkG.png)

Comment: Let the computer do the job, see [how to utilize event delegation and DOM structure](https://jsfiddle.net/brs8f9dL/2/).

Comment: Or even use the [datalist element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088227/adding-a-search-feature-to-html5-select). But be aware of [browsers support](https://caniuse.com/datalist)

Comment: when i try doing search on select ,its no gonna work it 
[link](https://nimb.ws/pRz29L) _italic_ **bold**

Comment: i tryed ,sreach function work ,but will not display my value to other input box

Comment: Your code works fine for a single element, you can see it in the images too, the cells are populated with the data. What is that "_other input box_" you want to show the value? If you're working with dynamic data and tables, you should forget classes as element identifiers, and utilize the robust DOM structure instead.

Comment: yes ,but will not popup in to the text box "Components ,Sell Price ,etc",

Comment: It does for a single element. Just take a look at the fiddle I've linked in the very first comment of this thread. It looks like that the JS code will work for you as it is with a small fix, in the `if`, assign `aspt = ['', '', '', '', '', ''];`, as there are some hidden elements to fill too.