# How to use the initial element as search box in select2?

Tags: html, jquery, search, jquery-select2

I essentially want the same functionality in a "single" select as in a "multiple" select. In the multiple select, the original element is also the search box:

[image: works in multiple]

In single select, there is a separate span for the result (in the example below it displays ProfitLoss) and the search box (newsearch).

[image]

Is there a way to collapse those two elements into one, where one simply edits the original element (in the example, one would edit the element containing "profitloss")?

I tried setting minimumResultsForSearch to -1, that did not do anything. ChatGPT also did not come with any useful answers.

Comment: Did you try html `datalist`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/38088403/18667225

Comment: Is there a way to link datalist to ajax calls? The list of potential suggestions is large (10K+), stored remotely and can change at any time.

Comment: Searching for "datalist ajax" I found this example on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jeremykenedy/nfnc5ogh/ . There are many more.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to customize HTML in handling events

First, You have to implement "multiple" select (Design the select field the same like the single one)

After then, you can do some customize in HTML by capturing the event

```
1. selecting
2. change
```

So, when the user selects the option, the `selecting` and `select` events are fired where you do your logic to customize the HTML, remove the item, OR add the item. It work like single select

I hope you got the idea